# How can i edit a TextView on OnClickListener

Tags: android

I have a problem to put text into a TextView. I just want to put the text writed into editTextNombre to tvMensaje

How can i do to solve this error? i canot find the problem....i just know that it is on the line 29 in the setText but i do not know because it return a error

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    EditText editTextNombre;
    String nombre;
    Button bMostrar;
    TextView tvMensaje;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        nombre="";
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tvMensaje=findViewById(R.id.textViewMensaje);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editTextNombre=findViewById(R.id.editTextNombre);
        bMostrar=findViewById(R.id.buttonMostrarNombre);
        bMostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nombre=editTextNombre.getText().toString();
                Log.i("valor:",nombre);
                tvMensaje.setText(nombre);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.textoplano, PID: 3027
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.textoplano.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
```

The problem is that not get the text correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

before finding textview

```
tvMensaje=findViewById(R.id.textViewMensaje);
```

So your onCreate should be like

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tvMensaje=findViewById(R.id.textViewMensaje);
        nombre="";        
        editTextNombre=findViewById(R.id.editTextNombre);
        bMostrar=findViewById(R.id.buttonMostrarNombre);
        bMostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nombre=editTextNombre.getText().toString();
                Log.i("valor:",nombre);
                tvMensaje.setText(nombre);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'findViewById' call returned a null because the 'textViewMensafe' View object didn't exist at the time it was called.  The 'setContentView' call takes the 'activity_main.xml' file with the layout information in it an creates the View objects.   So, if you move this statment:

```
tvMensaje=findViewById(R.id.textViewMensaje);
```

After this line:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

then the tvMensafe will not be null and you won't get the exception

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you're trying to find the ID of the `TextView` **BEFORE** the layout is actually set to the Activity.

You're getting `NullPointerException`, because the `TextView tvMensaje;` does not exist in the View hierarchy as you've not called `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in `onCreate()` of activity before trying to find the view.

You can correct it by calling `setContentView(R.layout.whatever)` before any operations related to `View`(like finding) are performed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    nombre="";
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvMensaje=findViewById(R.id.textViewMensaje);
}
```